# How to parse a large amount of data from a JSON webservice

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

I have a URL which returns a large amount of data in response, but I can't get a full response from the webservice URL. The webservice responds as follows:

> \"},
>   {\"minute_usage_end_time\":\"11:59\",\"minute_usage_start_time\":\"11:00\",\"kwh_usage\":\"0\",\"meter_reading_date\":\"08-02-2011\"},{...

What should I do?

Comment: could you be even less specific? I think `can't get a full response` is too much information at once. May be something more vague, like `it doesn't work` would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString(),HTTP.UTF_8);
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                Log.v("mas\n", reader.readLine());
                String jsonResultStr = reader.readLine();
```

Comment: i already use this but unable to get full response in string variable.

Comment: I use GSON for parsing Json response, it's very good and easy to use, you just need to make a model class for it.

Comment: Can you give any link or code where you  have used gson

Comment: And using Volley for WS calls. volley + gson = win

Comment: BibleKeywordSearch bibleKeywordSearch = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), BibleKeywordSearch.class); this is from one of my projects, The BibleKeywordSearch class is a model class for the JSON format. simple example json -> {book:Genesis,chapter:12,verse:56} and in the model class your variables name has to have the same name as the json keys. And generate getter and setter and simple constructor for it. OR When there is lot of data in response there are model class generators on the net. just copy the json and it generates the class http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/